# Manually resize window between prefixed dimensions

Tags: electron

I have a window that should only be resizable to a few dimensions:

```
315 x 250
580 x 185
991 x 135
1200 x 90
```

I'm trying to use the will-resize event like so:

```
win.on("will-resize", (event, bounds, edge) => {
         if (bounds.width < 580 && bounds.height < 250){
            event.preventDefault();
            win.setBounds({ height: 250 });
        }
        else if (bounds.width > 580 && bounds.height > 190){
            event.preventDefault();
            win.setBounds({ height : 190 })
        }
        else if (bounds.width < 990 && bounds.height > 135 ){
            event.preventDefault();
            win.setBounds({ height: 135 })
        } 

        else if (bounds.width > 991 && bounds.height > 90) {
            event.preventDefault();
            win.setBounds({ height: 90 })
        }
    });
```

There's an overlap in many of these cases so the logic doesn't work.

There's something super obvious here that I'm missing but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

So you have 4 defined window sizes you wish to abide by.

A question you will need to answer prior to coding is what happens if:

1. The width is in-range but the height is out-of-range, or
2. The height is in-range but the width is out-of-range.

Which way should you move your boundaries for a valid window? Horizontally (width) or vertically (height)?

```bash
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|               |               |               |               |
|       ?       |       ?       |       ?       |   1200 x 90   |
|               |               |               |               |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|               |               |               |
|       ?       |       ?       |   991 x 135   |       ?
|               |               |               | 
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|               |               |
|        ?      |   580 x 185   |       ?               ?
|               |               |
+---------------+---------------+
|               |
|   315 x 250   |       ?               ?               ?
|               |
+---------------+
```

Your current code only sets the height boundary and neglects any setting of the width boundary.

I have created a small test file below to test the logic. The "window size" logic is what's most important here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="width">Width: </label>
        <input type="text" id="width">

        <label for="height">Height: </label>
        <input type="text" id="height">

        <hr>

        <div>315 x 250 : <span id="small"></span></div>
        <div>580 x 185 : <span id="medium"></span></div>
        <div>991 x 135 : <span id="large"></span></div>
        <div>1200 x 90 : <span id="x-large"></span></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        let widthInput = document.getElementById('width');
        let heightInput = document.getElementById('height');
        let smallWindow = document.getElementById('small');
        let mediumWindow = document.getElementById('medium');
        let largeWindow = document.getElementById('large');
        let xLargeWindow = document.getElementById('x-large');

        widthInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => { calculate(); });
        heightInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => { calculate(); });

        function calculate() {
            if (widthInput.value.length === 0 || heightInput.value.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            smallWindow.innerText = '';
            mediumWindow.innerText = '';
            largeWindow.innerText = '';
            xLargeWindow.innerText = '';

            // Window size logic
            if (widthInput.value <= 315) { smallWindow.innerText = 'This one'; }
            if (widthInput.value > 315 && widthInput.value <= 580) { mediumWindow.innerText = 'This one'; }
            if (widthInput.value > 580 && widthInput.value <= 991) { largeWindow.innerText = 'This one'; }
            if (widthInput.value > 991) { xLargeWindow.innerText = 'This one'; }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Thus, converting this for use in your Electron application.

```js
win.on("will-resize", (event, bounds, edge) => {
    if (bounds.width <= 315) {
        event.preventDefault();
        win.setBounds({width: 315, height: 250});
    }

    if (bounds.width > 315 && bounds.width <= 580) {
        event.preventDefault();
        win.setBounds({width: 580, height: 185});
    }

    if (bounds.width > 580 && bounds.width <= 991) {
        event.preventDefault();
        win.setBounds({width: 991, height: 135});
    }

    if (bounds.width > 991) {
        event.preventDefault();
        win.setBounds({width: 1200, height: 90});
    }
});
```

If your use case / requirements vary to the above assumption then just let me know by updating your question for a more refined answer.